No se visualiza mi tabla
saludos tengo un problema, tengo mi archivo gestion_general.py y funcion_gestion_general.py el problema que tengo es que no se visualiza mi tabla en mi archivo gestion_general.py, es mi primer poryecto de python.
gestion_general.py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox 
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
# Python Image Library
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime 
from tkinter import ttk
import sys 
from funcion_gestion_general import *
from Conexion import Conexion
import sqlite3


class Gestion_general:
    def __init__(self):
    #def __init__(self, ventana_gestion_general):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        #Funcion_gestion_general.tabla_gestion_general(self)
        #self.window = ventana_gestion_general 
        self.window.title("CONSEJO COMUNAL LA SABANA / GESTIÓN GENERAL")
        self.window.geometry("900x550+250+100")
        self.window.configure(bg="#2874A6")
        self.window.resizable(0, 0)
        self.window.config(bd=10)

        # invocar conexion
        self.miconexion = Conexion()  # Crear una instancia de la clase Conexion
    
        # Crea los títulos
        tk.Label(self.window, text="CONSEJO COMUNAL LA SABANA", fg="white", bg="#2874A6",
                 font=("Arial Black", 15, "bold"), pady=20).pack()

        # iconos
        # Cargar imágenes
        imagen_buscar = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/yoclens/Desktop/CONSEJO3/imagenes/gestion_general.png")

        # label
        self.label_rif = tk.Label(self.window, text = 'Rif:')
        self.label_rif.config(font = ('Arial', 10, 'bold'), fg="white", bg="#2874A6")
        self.label_rif.place(x=100 , y=100)

        self.label_consejo_comunal = tk.Label(self.window, text = 'Consejo Comunal:')
        self.label_consejo_comunal.config(font = ('Arial', 10, 'bold'), fg="white", bg="#2874A6")
        self.label_consejo_comunal.place(x=250 , y=100)

        self.label_telefono = tk.Label(self.window, text = 'Teléfono:')
        self.label_telefono.config(font = ('Arial', 10, 'bold'), fg="white", bg="#2874A6")
        self.label_telefono.place(x=400 , y=100)

        self.label_banco = tk.Label(self.window, text = 'Banco:')
        self.label_banco.config(font = ('Arial', 10, 'bold'), fg="white", bg="#2874A6")
        self.label_banco.place(x=550 , y=100)

        self.label_numero_de_cuenta = tk.Label(self.window, text = 'Número de Cuenta:')
        self.label_numero_de_cuenta.config(font = ('Arial', 10, 'bold'), fg="white", bg="#2874A6")
        self.label_numero_de_cuenta.place(x=100 , y=160)

        self.label_sector = tk.Label(self.window, text = 'Sector:')
        self.label_sector.config(font = ('Arial', 10, 'bold'), fg="white", bg="#2874A6")
        self.label_sector.place(x=250 , y=160)

        self.label_parroquia = tk.Label(self.window, text = 'Parroquia:')
        self.label_parroquia.config(font = ('Arial', 10, 'bold'), fg="white", bg="#2874A6")
        self.label_parroquia.place(x=400 , y=160)

        self.label_municipio = tk.Label(self.window, text = 'Municipio:')
        self.label_municipio.config(font = ('Arial', 10, 'bold'), fg="white", bg="#2874A6")
        self.label_municipio.place(x=550 , y=160)

        self.label_estado = tk.Label(self.window, text = 'Estado:')
        self.label_estado.config(font = ('Arial', 10, 'bold'), fg="white", bg="#2874A6")
        self.label_estado.place(x=100 , y=230)

        # Cajas de texto
        self.rif = tk.StringVar()
        self.rif_entry = tk.Entry(self.window, textvariable = self.rif)
        self.rif_entry.place(x=100, y=120)

        self.consejo_comunal = tk.StringVar()
        self.consejo_comunal_entry = tk.Entry(self.window, textvariable = self.consejo_comunal)
        self.consejo_comunal_entry.place(x=250, y=120)

        self.telefono = tk.StringVar()
        self.telefono_entry = tk.Entry(self.window, textvariable = self.telefono)
        self.telefono_entry.place(x=400, y=120)

        self.banco = tk.StringVar()
        self.banco_entry = tk.Entry(self.window, textvariable = self.banco)
        self.banco_entry.place(x=550, y=120)

        self.numero_de_cuenta = tk.StringVar()
        self.numero_de_cuenta_entry = tk.Entry(self.window, textvariable = self.numero_de_cuenta)
        self.numero_de_cuenta_entry.place(x=100, y=180)

        self.sector = tk.StringVar()
        self.sector_entry = tk.Entry(self.window, textvariable = self.sector)
        self.sector_entry.place(x=250, y=180)

        self.parroquia = tk.StringVar()
        self.parroquia_entry = tk.Entry(self.window, textvariable = self.parroquia)
        self.parroquia_entry.place(x=400, y=180)

        self.municipio = tk.StringVar()
        self.municipio_entry = tk.Entry(self.window, textvariable = self.municipio)
        self.municipio_entry.place(x=550, y=180)

        self.estado = tk.StringVar()
        self.estado_entry = tk.Entry(self.window, textvariable = self.estado)
        self.estado_entry.place(x=100, y=250)


        # Botones del menú principal
        self.create_menu_buttons()


    def create_menu_buttons(self):
        # Crea los botones del menú principal
        menu_buttons = [
            ("Nuevo", self.nuevo_gestion_general),
            ("Agregar", self.agregar_gestion_general),
            ("Modificar", self.modificar_gestion_general),
            ("Eliminar", self.eliminar_gestion_general),
            ("Salir", self.salir_gestion_general)
        ]

        for i, (label, command) in enumerate(menu_buttons):
            tk.Button(self.window, text=label, height=1, width=10,
                      bg="white", fg="black", font=("Arial Black", 10, "bold"),
                      command=command).place(x=100 + i * 120, y=290)

    def nuevo_gestion_general(self):
        self.rif.config(state="disabled")
        self.consejo_comunal.config(state="disabled")
        self.telefono.config(state="disabled")
        self.banco.config(state="disabled")
        self.numero_de_cuenta.config(state="disabled")
        self.sector.config(state="disabled")
        self.parroquia.config(state="disabled")
        self.municipio.config(state="disabled")
        self.estado.config(state="disabled")

    def desbloquerar_gestion_general(self):
        self.rif.config(state="normal")
        self.consejo_comunal.config(state="normal")
        self.telefono.config(state="normal")
        self.banco.config(state="normal")
        self.numero_de_cuenta.config(state="normal")
        self.sector.config(state="normal")
        self.parroquia.config(state="normal")
        self.municipio.config(state="normal")
        self.estado.config(state="normal")
        
    def limpiar(self):
        self.rif.set('')
        self.consejo_comunal.set('')
        self.telefono.set('')
        self.banco.set('')
        self.numero_de_cuenta.set('')
        self.sector.set('')
        self.parroquia.set('')
        self.municipio.set('')
        self.estado.set('')



    def agregar_gestion_general(self):
        Funcion_gestion_general.agregar_gestion_general(self)
        self.limpiar()



    def modificar_gestion_general(self):
      
        pass

    def eliminar_gestion_general(self):
      
        pass

    def salir_gestion_general(self):
        self.window.destroy()
        pass


    def tabla_gestion_general(self):
        Funcion_gestion_general.tabla_gestion_general(self)
        
        
       
    def run(self):
        self.window.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Gestion_general()
    app.run()

funcion_gestion_general.py
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk 
from Conexion import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
from tkinter import scrolledtext as st
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas


def limpiar(self):
        self.rif.set('')
        self.consejo_comunal.set('')
        self.telefono.set('')
        self.banco.set('')
        self.numero_de_cuenta.set('')
        self.sector.set('')
        self.parroquia.set('')
        self.municipio.set('')
        self.estado.set('')
        
        #funcion_gestion_general.tabla_gestion_general()


class Funcion_gestion_general:

    print("Imported funcion_gestion_general.py") 

    def agregar_gestion_general(self):
        if not all([self.rif.get(), self.consejo_comunal.get(), self.telefono.get(),
                    self.banco.get(), self.numero_de_cuenta.get(), self.sector.get(),
                    self.parroquia.get(), self.municipio.get(), self.estado.get()]):
            mb.showinfo(message="Por favor, completa todos los campos.", title="Validación de Campos")
        else:
            try:
                datos = (self.rif.get(), self.consejo_comunal.get(), self.telefono.get(),
                    self.banco.get(), self.numero_de_cuenta.get(), self.sector.get(),
                    self.parroquia.get(), self.municipio.get(), self.estado.get())
                cursor = self.miconexion.obtener_cursor()
                sql = "INSERT INTO gestion_general (rif, consejo_comunal, telefono, banco, numero_de_cuenta, sector, parroquia, municipio, estado) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
                cursor.execute(sql, datos)
                self.miconexion.commit()
                mb.showinfo(message="¡Datos ingresados correctamente!", title="Ingreso de Datos")
                #some_object.limpiar()
            except sqlite3.Error:
                mb.showerror(message="Disculpe este registo ya existe", title="Validación")


    def modificar_gestion_general(self):
        if not self.entry_id_gestion_general.get():
            mb.showinfo(message="Debe haber un Id de referencia", title="Validación de Campos")
        else:
            try:
                cursor = self.miconexion.cursor()
                sql = """UPDATE gestion_general SET rif=?, consejo_comunal=?, telefono=?, banco=?, numero_de_cuenta=?, sector=?, parroquia=?, municipio=?, estado=? WHERE id_gestion_genral = ?"""
                datos_act = (
                    self.entry_rif.get(),
                    self.entry_consejo_comunal.get(),
                    self.entry_telefono.get(),
                    self.entry_banco.get(),
                    self.entry_numero_de_cuenta.get(),
                    self.entry_sector.get(),
                    self.entry_parroquia.get(),
                    self.entry_municipio.get(),
                    self.entry_estado.get(),
                    self.entry_id_gestion_genral.get())
                cursor.execute(sql, datos_act)
                self.miconexion.commit()
                mb.showinfo(title="Actualizar registro", message="Se pudo actualizar el registro.")
            except sqlite3.Error:
                mb.showerror(title="Actualizar registro", message="No se pudo actualizar el registro.")


    def tabla_gestion_general(self):
        tabla_gestion_general = ('N°', 'Rif', 'Consejo Comunal', 'Teléfono', 'Banco', 'Numero de Cuenta', 'Sector', 'Parroquia', 'Municipio', 'Estado')
        tree = ttk.Treeview(self.window, columns=tabla_gestion_general, show='headings')
        tree.heading('N°', text='N°')
        tree.heading('Rif', text='Rif')
        tree.heading('Consejo Comunal', text='Consejo Comunal')
        tree.heading('Teléfono', text='Teléfono')
        tree.heading('Banco', text='Banco')
        tree.heading('Numero de Cuenta', text='Numero de Cuenta')
        tree.heading('Sector', text='Sector')
        tree.heading('Parroquia', text='Parroquia')
        tree.heading('Municipio', text='Municipio')
        tree.heading('Estado', text='Estado')

        try:
            cursor = self.miconexion.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM gestion_general")
            tabla_gestion_general = cursor.fetchall()
            for dato in tabla_gestion_general:
                tree.insert('', tk.END, values=dato[:])
        except sqlite3.DatabaseError as e:
            print("Error al obtener datos:", e)
        finally:
            self.miconexion.close()

        tabla_frame = tk.Frame(self.window)
        tabla_frame.place(x=10, y=335)
        tree.pack(in_=tabla_frame, fill='both', expand=True)

